# How to measure growth rates of page views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Our main challenge in Google Analytics at the time is to measure the success of our magazine articles.

The problem is that views grow over time so in any timeframe we always have the older articles overshadowing the newer ones. Sidenote: The same problem occurs for measuring social media post success.

My idea of a solution is to measure the rate by which views on articles grow. An article that has a higher growth of views is much more successful than an older article with more views, but with a lower growth rate.

Alternatively something like "views within the first week(s) of publishing this individual article" would also be a good metric.

Unfortunately to some extent also the growth rates rely on this publishing period of individual articles if we are interested in an eternal high score of articles. But since we are mainly interested in recent articles, growth rate would still give us the desired result of showing the most successful recent articles.

Has anyone dealt with the same challenges and found any solution to this, in best case with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These examples may help, of which I have direct experience.

1. In the data layer we included a date of publication for the article and then used this to determine growth. This was taken from the CRM and was relatively straightforwards for the dev team. This was stored as a custom dimension in Google Analytics.
2. We had nothing in the data layer but instead a I just used the date on which page views started appearing as a proxy for date of publication. Not entirely reliable, and you may want to filter by views >5, or whatever is appropriate, to avoid any hits from editors or staff before a page is visible in the site navigation.

In both cases I was exporting data either to Google Sheets (using for example the Google Analytics API addon for sheets) or BigQuery, where it was relatively straight forwards to identify the first date and then calculate, for example, views per day. In your case it would be having a function which looks at the date of publication + 7 days. You may also be able to achieve this with Google Data Studio or similar dashboarding platform.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the insightful and actionable advice!